# Collapse when click on the expanded section and expand other section

Tags: javascript

I have attached the code. Here the section will collapse when we open/expand other section.But not collapsing when we click on the opened button.
I want to achieve collapsion of the section on both the cases:
 collapse when clicking on the opened button as well as click on other sections

Please help with this. Thanks in advance

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // before opening the accordion, you close everything
    for (var j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
      coll[j].classList.remove("active");
      coll[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:30px;
  left: 13%;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:35px;
  height:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 1030px) {
  .centered {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }
  
 #container {
  display:flex;
  margin-left:50px;
  align-items: center;
}  
}

.column {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 200px; 
  margin: -20px;
  width: 430px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 48px;
 }
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height:55px;

}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 40px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin:0px;
}

#container {
  display:flex;
  margin-left:10px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:-12px;
}
#container > * {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.maincontainer{
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top:-20px;
}
.card-heading{
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
h4{
 font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
h2{
 font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; 
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}
.sub-container{
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">

<div class="collapsible">
  <span id="container">
      <img src="test.png" width="45" height="45" alt="">
      <span class="sub-container">Heading</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sub-heading">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
 <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div>
<div class="sub-heading">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

  

</div>

<div class="collapsible">
  <span id="container">
      <img src="test.png" width="45" height="45" alt="">
      <span class="sub-container">Heading</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="content">
 <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div>
<div class="sub-heading">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

  
</div>
 


<div class="collapsible">
  <span id="container">
      <img src="test.png" width="45" height="45" alt="">
      <span class="sub-container">Heading</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="sub-heading">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div>
<div class="sub-heading">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
    <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40"  style="float: left;"/></div>
   <div class="card-heading"><h4>TEXT</h4></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: well, the problem seems to be that you first remove the active css class, before you toggle it (so it will always be added again), maybe validate if the element that just got clicked, is the one from which you removed the `active` css class?

Comment: @IcepickleThanks for your reply..I tried your suggestion, but that's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var col1 = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');
let lastClick;
let content;

[...col1].forEach(col => {
  col.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Check if last clicked ele is same as current and it has 'active' class
    if (this == lastClick && this.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.classList.remove('active');
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
      return;
    }
    // Remove active class from all elements along with maxheight to null
    [...col1].forEach(col => {
      col.classList.remove('active')
      col.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    });
    
    // Add active to clicked element and apply the height to the next element sibling.
    this.classList.add('active');
    content = this.nextElementSibling;
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    lastClick = this;
  });
})
```

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  left: 13%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 1030px) {
  .centered {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #container {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 50px;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.column {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: -20px;
  width: 430px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 48px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 55px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 40px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

#container>* {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.maincontainer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.card-heading {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

h4 {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sub-container {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">

  <div class="collapsible">
    <span id="container">
                <img src="test.png" width="45" height="45" alt="">
                <span class="sub-container">Heading</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sub-heading">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="sub-heading">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>

  <div class="collapsible">
    <span id="container">
                <img src="test.png" width="45" height="45" alt="">
                <span class="sub-container">Heading</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="sub-heading">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>



  <div class="collapsible">
    <span id="container">
                <img src="test.png" width="45" height="45" alt="">
                <span class="sub-container">Heading</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="sub-heading">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="45" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="sub-heading">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div><img src="test.png" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;" /></div>
        <div class="card-heading">
          <h4>TEXT</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the function check if "active" is in classList:

```
var isActive = this.classList.contains("active");
```

Then, after closing everything exit the function if `isActive`

```
if (isActive) return;
```

When you click an open section, it will be the only one, because you make sure that there will be always at most one open section.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a bit to much work here, there is no need to iterate through all of your elements to remove the active list first. You will only have 1 active, so query that one, and remove the active class, then once you are done, you could compare if that one is the same header that just got clicked or not. In case it is, you are done, as you already removed the `active` css class.

Otherwise, you just have to add the `active` class and you are also done.

An overly simplified solution would be the following one

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion > .panel').forEach( p => {
  p.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const { currentTarget } = e;
    const activePanel = document.querySelector('.active');
    
    // if there is an active panel, remove the active css class
    activePanel && activePanel.classList.remove('active');
    if (activePanel === currentTarget) {
      // if it's the current panel, we are done
      return;
    }
    // otherwise set the current target to active
    currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  } );
} );
```

```css
.panel > .content {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.panel > h1 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.panel > h1:after {
  content: '+';
}
.panel.active > .content {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
.panel.active > h1 {
  background: #777;
  color: #000;
}
.panel.active > h1:after {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```